# Detect Javascript event type

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js

There is a function OPEN in my javascript which is called when the user either blur (lose focus on the input field) or hit Enter.

Then within OPEN(), depending on whether it was triggered by blur or keypress, it leads to two different other functions.

For the Keypress, I did it like this.

```
        if (e.keyCode==13) ENTER_FX();
```

How do you do this for BLUR

Thank you

UPDATE:

I found that it should be e.type=="focusout"

So is focusout the right word instead of blur?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**[WORKING JSFIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6CA7S/9/)**

```
e.type
```

gives you this information

```
function OPEN(e) {
    if (e.type !== "blur") {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {
            ENTER_FX();
        }
    }
    else {
        ENTER_FX();
    }
}
```

Comment: It depends on the way you attached it... If you attach it to `onfocusout` surely it will report that the event type will be `focusout`, same story with blur.

Comment: I attached it to a blur event. Through the backbone.js api. But anyways, it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`e.type` should probably say 'blur' in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Try `if(e.type == "blur") /*code here*/`

[`event.type` reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.type)

Comment: No luck. On blur, everything else in OPEN() is performed, except those under the if e.type...

Comment: @William That's strange. Can you try putting `alert(e.type)` or `console.log(e.type)` in your event handler?